# Why do I lose my buffered video content when I let the video buffer fully beforehand?

Tags: youtube

I have always faced this problem on YouTube. What I do is let the video buffer completely and watch it after that. When I click on play it plays fine, but when I move the bar that tells the current time position in the video, everything that is buffered is lost. It starts loading buffering from there. Especially, when the bar is drawn to the extreme left, this happens.

I have always had this issue with YouTube but not on Metacafe.

Does this happen to you? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand what you are saying, this has happened with me a lot of time.

**First of all never move the slider to the extreme left.**

When you open the video page, the video starts buffering automatically, now when you change the video quality from 360p to 240p (say), the content already loaded is lost and new buffering starts at 240p from the time 00:01 (sec) (or may be even a fraction of a second difference).

Saying that, if you move the slider to a portion of the video that has not been downloaded at all (00:00 is not downloaded at all - it was downloaded at 360p but then lost), all the downloaded content is again lost and the video starts buffering again from the point you have set the slider in.

**What is it when it is not extreme left?**

You have started viewing a video, the progress bar shows at to up-to which extent the video has been downloaded and you move the slider to a point within that range, but still you loose all the content and buffering starts again - WHY?

This is because there are a lot of problems with the YouTube's progress bar. The progress is always actually a few seconds behind what is shown in the progress bar. And also sometimes, the progress level is completely lost and the player shows that the video is downloaded till the end, but it is not - And as I have already said above, moving the slider to a point where the video has not been downloaded makes you loose all the content and starts buffering from that point.

Comment: Thank you.
I wonder why they haven't made it such that it adds up the downloaded portions of the video lets say I jump and go to a not downloaded point. 

Not only that,I've also had issues where going back to a downloaded portion has similar issues.

Comment: @learner I can't say as to why it is not made like that as we do not have any technical knowledge in the field of making websites etc... Going back to the downloaded portions....i have no idea about that - I think you are mistaken.

Comment: I also have the problem and it's not related with not yet downloaded parts or changes of the stream quality. I just click somewhere where it clearly has already downloaded (and played), and it starts downloading again. Happens in some videos, in others not.