# Why do some YouTube videos start loading everything again once you click somewhere?

Tags: youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I lose my buffered video content when I let the video buffer fully beforehand?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27396/why-do-i-lose-my-buffered-video-content-when-i-let-the-video-buffer-fully-before)

Why some YouTube videos start load everything again every time you click somewhere in the already loaded track?

I have limited bandwidth, and if I want to see something repeatedly, it will load each time again... happens with some videos, with others it just plays again without reloading.

Comment: Has it anything to do with the length of the video? Maybe the (browser) cache is full and therefore a reload is necessary?

Comment: My understanding is that it streams again from the place where you clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The YouTube video player is quite unstable in that sense. Sometimes it will reload the video and sometimes it won't (either because the resolution of the video changed, or the cache is full, etc).

If you play the video completely and then go back and watch it again (pressing the replay button), you should be just fine.

Additionally, if this becomes a grave problem, I recommend downloading the videos with the following websites:

- [KeepVid](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGsQFjAA&url=http://keepvid.com/&ei=GFULUObgIOLvmAXliKSbCg&usg=AFQjCNEVs_F0d7oBflVNpMu2_dEGvH-ZjA&sig2=uVREntO8TizSnAO_ZGREZg)
- [Keep-Tube](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CHQQFjAE&url=http://keep-tube.com/&ei=GFULUObgIOLvmAXliKSbCg&usg=AFQjCNGqQiMwtDJHRjh2LSNmgF4tmevwBA&sig2=JIJ7XU2pkCHkykPC-ZZDwA)

(Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with either of the sites; I'm just suggesting what has worked for me. However, I'm not responsible for the functioning/availability of such services).

Comment: This is inherently a caching thing. It might clear the cache for parts of the video you've already seen – because in essence there's no real need to keep those around forever. Clicking again requests the video chunk from the server and thus takes a little to load.

Comment: @slhck: true, it's not imperative to keep them *forever*, but YouTube Player should keep them there at least for as long as the video is open.